# How to provide non-admins of Site Collection with Access to Audit Logs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, audit-log-reports

I'm working in SharePoint On-Prem 2016, and am curious if you know of a way to grant someone who isn't a site collection admin with access to review the Audit Logs?  (Trying to make it sort of "self-service" so some users can get to the data in the logs of "who opened a file" without having to contact the IT Dept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export them on a scheduled basis to a Document library on the same Site Collection. That is the easiest approach.

Comment: Do you think the export would be a manual process I'd need to do?  Trying to see if there's a way to automate this as much as possible.

Comment: In the options for audit logging there is a 'trim audit log' along with an export to a Doc Lib. This is an automated process.